# How do I access headphones mode using Realtek drivers without the device popup?

Tags: audio, drivers, headphones

My laptop's realtek audio was able to simulate a speaker set with my headphones.
By this I mean that it knew that in a real surround speaker set, both ears would actually hear a sound playing from only the right speaker, so it played a lower volume from the left earpiece for sounds that software told it to come out of only the right speaker. It would do this only when I selected "Headphones" from the popup that appears when I connect my headphones, however.

I've recently built a new desktop machine, and it does not perform this functionality, and I do not know how to enable it, because the headphones popup doesn't come up.

Spec comparison:

- Laptop

  - Windows 8.1
  - Drivers from 2012
  - Unsure about hardware
- Desktop

  - Windows 7
  - Tried most recent drivers from Realtek and from MB manufacturer
  - Motherboard is [Asrock 97ZM OC Formula](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z97M%20OC%20Formula/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Headphone Virtualization.

To enable it using Realtek drivers that do not display a popup when a new device is connected, you must explicitly select Stereo instead of 5.1 or 7.1. Once this is done, a Headphone Virtualization checkbox will appear near the bottom of the Realtek configuration window.

Check this box to enable the desired functionality.